# How to embed a date command into json request

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create nightly releases of a private repo via GitHubs API. I would like to add the date to the nightly release via the `date` command provided by bash. But I don't know how to escape the command. This is what I would like to accomplish.

```
curl -u "$1:$2" -XPOST \
  "https://api.github.com/repos/RazortoothRTC/ambra-nocigramweb-webhook/releases" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"tag_name":"ambra-nocigramweb-webhook-nightly",\
       "target_commitish":"master",\
       "name":"nightly-**$(date +%d-%m-%Y)**",\
       "body":"Nightly release of ambra-nocigramweb-webhook",\
       "draft":false,\
       "prerelease":false}'
```

It's not evident but I want to embed a `$(date +%d-%m-%Y)` into the json post request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jq` to generate the date safely along with the rest of your JSON.

```
json=$(jq -n '{
   tag_name: "ambra-nocigramweb-webhook-nightly",
   target_commitish: "master",
   name: "nightly-\(now|gmtime|strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))",
   body: "Nightly release of ambra-nocigramweb-webhook",
   draft: false,
   prerelease: false
 }')
```

Comment: This is the only answer here (as of this comment's posting) that can't create malformed output if generalized to other data -- the other answers will behave badly if instead of using `$(date)` one is calling a program whose output can have literal quotes, literal newlines, or other content that needs to be modified to be parsed as JSON; whereas any JQ-based approach is guaranteed to generate well-formed content or to fail outright.

Comment: Do the keys not have double quotes on purpose? Should it be "tag_name" instead of tag_name?

Comment: @user3577138, this is correct as-given -- the output from `jq` will have the quotes necessary for it to be syntactically valid JSON. (It would also be correct with the quotes in the input, but they aren't necessary). `jq` is a JSON-processing tool, not a string-processing tool, so it **can't** emit invalid output unless explicitly placed in raw-string mode.

Comment: You *can* quote keys in a `jq` filter (and some keys *must* be quoted), but I prefer to leave them unquoted when possible, to cut down on the "noise".

Comment: When I use the `$(jq ...)` command I get GH API errors. `"message": "Invalid request.\n\n\"tag_name\" wasn't supplied.",`

Comment: Are you quoting `$json` when you use it as the argument to `curl`?

Comment: @chepner that fixed it. I wasn't quoting $json

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running `$()` inside `'...'`, it is [not going to be evaluated](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html). Try something like this instead:

```
curl ... -d '{..., "name":"nightly-'$(date +%d-%m-%Y)'", ...}'
```

By doing this, the result of the sub-shell call `$()` is going to be evaluated **before** constructing the parameter string for `curl -d`.

A more readable version would look like this:

```
DATE=$(date +%d-%m-%Y)
curl ... -d '{..., "name":"nightly-'$DATE'", ...}'
```

Comment: I tried the "readable" version and I get the literal string `$DATE` in the string still

Comment: sorry - fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The usage of simple quote prevent bash from interpreting the string.
Double quotes would do but you need them inside json.

So you can use `printf`:

```
printf '{"tag_name":"ambra-nocigramweb-webhook-nightly","target_commitish":"master","name":"nightly-**%s**","body":"Nightly release of ambra-nocigramweb-webhook","draft":false,"prerelease":false}' $(date +%d-%m-%Y)

{"tag_name":"ambra-nocigramweb-webhook-nightly","target_commitish":"master","name":"nightly-**03-02-2018**","body":"Nightly release of ambra-nocigramweb-webhook","draft":false,"prerelease":false}
```

`printf` is usually a better practice in bash.

You can even use templates:

```
$ template='{"tag_name":"ambra-nocigramweb-webhook-nightly","target_commitish":"master","name":"nightly-**%s**","body":"Nightly release of ambra-nocigramweb-webhook","draft":false,"prerelease":false}'

$ printf "$template" $(date +%d-%m-%Y)

{"tag_name":"ambra-nocigramweb-webhook-nightly","target_commitish":"master","name":"nightly-**03-02-2018**","body":"Nightly release of ambra-nocigramweb-webhook","draft":false,"prerelease":false}
```